# .NoClassDefFoundError when trying to use pdfBox

Tags: java, exception, pdfbox

when I try to use one of the `PDFBox` examples for extracting images, in the run time,it gives me the following exception:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.<clinit>(BaseParser.java:68)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1218)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1186)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1111)
    at pdfboxtest.PdfBoxTest.extractImage(PdfBoxTest.java:69)
    at pdfboxtest.PdfBoxTest.main(PdfBoxTest.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

here is the part of the code that exception occurs, at the last two lines:

```
         String pdfFile = "pdf file path";
         File pdf=new  File(pdfFile);
         PDDocument document = null;
         document = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(pdf, null, password);
         document = PDDocument.load( pdfFile );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add commons-logging-1.1.1.jar 
or
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.6.jar in your lib directory.

Comment: I did and it fixed. but this is ridiculous . if had to add that jar, why the package didnt include it?

Comment: It is a documented dependency. It is not ridiculous but instead sensible to not repackage and repackage again common classes in each jar. If you used Maven, that dependency would automatically be supplied.

Answer (score 1):

Download jar file from the following [Link](http://commons.apache.org/logging/download_logging.cgi). Add it to your class path.

Answer (score 1):

Add the required [dependency](http://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/dependencies.html) to your class-path (from the link)

> The main PDFBox component, pdfbox, has a hard dependency on [commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/)

Answer (score 1):

For someone using `PDFBox 2.0.4`, you need to add `debugger-app-2.0.4.jar` in your **Libraries** directory